Código de Interpolación de HErmite no muestra la gráfica
desde varios días he intentado hacer un código en python que calcule el polinomio interpolante de Hermite y una aproximación al valor de x, del siguiente ejercicio:
Sea $3xe^x-e^{2x}$
Aproxime $f(1.03)$ por medio del polinomio interpolante de Hermite de grado tres utilizando $x_0=1$     y   $x_1=1.05$. Compare el error real con la cota de error.
Repita a) con el polinomio interpolante de Hermite de grado 5, utilizando
$x_0=1 $     $ x_1=1.05$  y    $ x_2=1.07$
ya lo he conseguido. el problema es que , el código me muestra el polinomio interpolador mas la aproximación pero no me muestra la gráfica del polinomio interpolante. espero puedan ayudarme, les anexo el código.
el ejercicio es el siguiente:
he resuelto el polinomio de grado 5, pero no muestra la gráfica, espero puedan ayudarme.
 import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, lambdify, expand, pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = Symbol('x')

def diferencia(x , y , yp):
    n = len(x)
    z = np.empty(shape= 2 * n, dtype=float)
    Q = np.zeros(shape=(2 * n, 2 * n), dtype=float)
    d =np.empty(shape=2 * n, dtype=float)
    
    for i in np.arange(n):
        z[2 * i ] = x[i]
        z[2 * i + 1]= x[i]
        Q[2 * i][0]  = y[i]
        Q[2 * i + 1][0] = y[i]
        Q[2 * i + 1][1] = yp[i]
        if i !=0:
            Q[2 * i ][1] = (Q[2 * i ][0] - Q[2 * i - 1][0]) / (z[2 * i] - z[2 * i - 1])
        
    for i in np.arange (2 , 2 * (n - 1) + 2):
        for j in np.arange(2, i + 1 ):
                f = Q[i][j-1] - Q[i - 1][j - 1]
                g = z[i] - z[i - j]
                Q[i][j] = f / g
    d = Q.diagonal()
    return z, d

def polhermitesym(diff, z):
    n = len(z) - 1
    pol = diff[n]
    for k in np.arange(1, n + 1):
        pol = diff[n - k] + (x - z[n - k])*pol
    return pol

if '_name_' "" '_maín_' :
    datos_x = np.array([1, 1.05, 1.07], dtype=float)
    datos_y = np.array([0.7657893864, 0.8354311093, 0.858930566], dtype=float )
    datos_yp =[1.531578773, 1.242214551, 1.105631437]
    
    d = diferencia(datos_x, datos_y, datos_yp)
    diff = d[1]
    polhermitesym = polhermitesym(diff, d[0])
    pprint(' el polinomio interpolador de Hermite es : ')
    pprint(expand(polhermitesym))
    pprint(' el valor aproximado obtenido con x={0} es H({0})={1}'.format(1.03, polhermitesym.subs(x, 1.03)))
    polisimple = polhermitesym.expand()
    px = lambdify(x,polisimple)
    muestras = 101
    pxi = np.linspace(-2,5, muestras)
    pfi = px(pxi)
    plt.plot(datos_x, datos_y,'0', label = 'puntos')
    plt.plot(pxi,pfi, label ='polinomio')
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('xi')
    plt.ylabel('fi')
    plt.title('interpolacion de Hermite')
    
    


Gracias por la ayuda, ya pude ver la gráfica, cómo dije en mi mensaje anterior este código es de interpolación de Hermite. Ya conseguí el valor aproximado al polinomio dado. Mi pregunta es la siguiente: cómo puedo añadirle a este ejercicio el cálculo del error real? Que sería evaluar la función que me han dado en el ejercicio en el punto 1.03 y luego restarle el valor que he obtenido en la aproximación del polinomio interpolante. Pueden ayudarme a codificar esto?

Cosas a tener en cuenta:

Si no estás ejecutando ese código en un Notebook de Jupyter, necesitas llamar explícitamente a matplotlib.pyplot.show() al final de todo para que se muestren todas las figuras, es decir:
...
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('xi')
plt.ylabel('fi')
plt.title('interpolacion de Hermite')
plt.show()

En caso contrario no se mostrará la gráfica.

El formato "0" (plt.plot(datos_x, datos_y, '0', label='puntos')) no es válido. Si quieres círculos como marca sería "o".

Es if __name__ == '__maín__':



Hola, gracias por tu ayuda. Si quiero calcular el error real, que sería evaluar la función en el punto 1.03 de la función que me han dado y a ese resultado restarle lo obtenido en la aproximación del polinomio de Hermite, que debo hacer?
